# Unable to pass dotenv file to another stage in CI/CD

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have a pretty large CI/CD pipeline with 5 stages.
In the first stage "build" I set up the dotenv file, which I want to use in some later stages. I did that [according to the docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job), but somehow I can't pass the dotenv file to another job/stage.

The relevant snipped of gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - create-image
  - post-image-creation
  # rest omitted for simplicity

image: alpine:3.14.3

setup-dotenv-file:
  stage: build
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  script:
    - echo "Setting up build.env file"
    - echo "On branch $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    - |
      if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "test" ]]; then
        cat $TEST_ENV_FILE > build.env && source build.env
      elif [[ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "stage" ]]; then
        cat $STAGE_ENV_FILE > build.env && source build.env
      elif [[ "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" == "master" ]]; then
        cat $PROD_ENV_FILE > build.env && source build.env
      else
        echo "No environment file found for this branch."
      fi
    - ls -la
  only:
    - test
    - stage
    - master

# create image jobs omitted for simplicity

post-template-lab:
  stage: post-image-creation
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-7.2-alpine-3.14
  variables: 
    ErrorActionPreference: stop
  tags:
    - pwsh
  script:
    - cd General/Scripts
    - .\post-template.ps1 -paramter1 $VARIABLE_FROM_DOTENVFILE -paramter2 $VARIABLE_FROM_DOTENVFILE
  retry: 2
  needs:
    - setup-dotenv-file
    - # multiple jobs from create-image stage
  only:
    - test
```

When running the pipeline I can see the build.env file created and uploaded:

```
Uploading artifacts...
build.env: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "dotenv" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=7527 responseStatus=201 Created token=xxxxxxx
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
```

However I can't see it in the web interface: [image: Artifact overview is empty on webinterface]

And when the `post-template-lab job` is running
I get the error, that the variable is not defined.

I've tried different variations with `dependencies:` and `needs:` but none worked. I thought maybe it's because I'm using different images/scripting languages, and I need to reload the dotenv file in powershell in the later stage, but that is not possible at the moment, because the file does not get passed to the job:

```bash
$ ls -la # result in the post-template-lab job
22total 52
23drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root          4096 Sep 15 08:23 .
24drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Aug 29 15:26 ..
25-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           745 Sep 15 08:23 .env.sample
26drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Sep 15 09:52 .git
27-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           703 Sep 15 08:23 .gitignore
28-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          1608 Sep 15 08:23 .gitlab-ci.yml
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I can't see it in the web interface

dotenv reports are not directly exposed in the artifacts web interface. It is normal that you cannot see or download dotenv reports

> the file does not get passed to the job

Additionally, dotenv reports are not downloaded like other job artifacts. The report file is read and environment variables are set for the job, but you won't see the file itself in subsequent jobs, roughly, as if set in the `variables:` key.

```
set-variables:
  script:
    - echo "FOO=foo" > variables.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: variables.env

my-job:
  needs: [set-variables]
  script:
    - echo $FOO  # foo
    - env
```

If the variable you're expecting is not present, you should make sure you're forming the file correctly. Note that there are [restrictions on what can be placed in a dotenv file in GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/artifacts_reports.html#artifactsreportsdotenv) which is more strict than what is typically allowed in a .env file.

If you want to consume the .env file like a normal artifact, just use `artifacts:paths:` instead of `artifacts:reports:dotenv`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I've managed to get the variables passed to some jobs, however they're not set in the jobs that use the powershell image, so I switched to ```artifacts:paths:``` anyway.